# Query function with date in Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to return column M when the date matches the date in column I. Any idea why it says N/A when I run the query function? [image]

Here's the formula I'm trying to make work.

=QUERY(A2:M1000,"select M where(I='4/8/2016')")

Comment: Here's a dummy data example spreadsheet for reference. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kYF7KUAGEfynehYkVyWYNWPIfQkR2rKziFhyVDsAlC0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:M1000,"select M where I=date '"&text(P1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'")
```